# My Laravel 5.2 Session doesn't persist when I access a link from Whatsapp(in particular)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Basically the title.

When I share a link from my application on Whatsapp the link redirect to login. Always and only on whatsapp(not on mobile). Discord, facebook etc it does'nt happen. Can someone help with this issue?

**UPDATE**

This is the link from Whatsapp

```
<a href="https://mylaravelsite.com.br/somepage/9999" title="https://mylaravelsite.com.br/somepage/9999" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="_3FXB1 selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text">https://mylaravelsite.com.br/somepage/9999</a>
```

Comment: If you try accessing the link from a browser that you're not logged in to, it'll definitely redirect to login.

Comment: I'm logged in. The scenario is. I have two tabs on the same browser. One is my website, and the other is whatsapp web. When someone share a link from my website on whats and I click in it, it redirect me to the login page, even if I am already logged in

Comment: Hi, I think you should include more about how your routes are setup in laravel.